# The Marker That I`m trying to Make it Apear is returning null in MAUI

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui, mobile-development

I need to convert a XAMARIN Code to a MAUI system. So there is an image which have to make it appear when i`ve searched something. But the image is returning null. I do not know why is it returning null, the path to the folder is selected in the code. But yet it do not return the image.

```
 private static SymbolStyle CreateMarkerStyle(string embeddedResourcePath, double scale)
    {
        try
        {
            var bitmapId = GetBitmapIdForEmbeddedResource(embeddedResourcePath); //From here I`m trying to get the photo.
            return new SymbolStyle { BitmapId = bitmapId, SymbolScale = scale, SymbolOffset = new Offset(0, 256) };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        
    }
```

From here I`m returning to this code.

```
  public MemoryLayer SearchMarkerLayer
    {
        
        get
        {
            if (_markerLayer == null)
            {
                _markerLayer = new MemoryLayer
                {
                    Name = "Sorgu Sonuçları",
                    MaxVisible = BingMapsLayer.Resolutions[8],
                    IsMapInfoLayer = true,
                    Style = CreateMarkerStyle("AGROWORKS.MOBILE.Images.location-pin.svg", 0.1) // This is the image I`m trying to make it appear.
                };
            }

            return _markerLayer;
        }
    }
```

And from there we return in here:

```
    private static int GetBitmapIdForEmbeddedResource(string imagePath)
    {
        try
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var image = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(imagePath); //And here is the path of my image file. 
            var bitmapId = BitmapRegistry.Instance.Register(image); //Which returns null.
            return bitmapId;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: resources are not files and are not referenced using paths

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `var image = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(imagePath);` - what is the value of `imagePath`?

Comment: it directly connects to the image path that i have written in the SearchMarkerLayer class, which is: `Style = CreateMarkerStyle("AGROWORKS.MOBILE.Images.location-pin.svg", 0.1)` so the value is: AGROWORKS.MOBILE.Images.location-pin.svg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have test your code in the maui project, and it return an int value not null.

My code:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var image = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MauiApp39.Mobile.Image.dotnet_bot.svg");
var bitmap = BitmapRegistry.Instance.Register(image);
```

The debug result:

[image]

And the structure of my project:

[image]

**Note: I used the NugetPackage MapSui.Maui 4.0.0-bete.9 and set the image's build action as Embedded resource.**